# MySQL Statement not echoing variable in while

Tags: php, mysql

So I have the following:

```
$query = "SELECT id,account,status FROM service WHERE status = 'Unpaid'";
        $result = mysql_query($query);  

    while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)){

                $id = $row[0];
                $dateEntered = $row[1];
                $type = $row[2];
                $account = $row[3];
                $dateCompleted = $row[4];
                $notes = $row[5];
                $status = $row[6];

            echo $account;
          // mailStatusUpdate($account, $status, $dateEntered);

        }   

echo mysql_error();
```

Query processes fine in phpmyadmin. When I echo the $account of the unpaid status records, it doesn't echo. Whats the problem? PHPmyadmin processes everything fine and shows me the records?

Comment: Variable is row[3] and is not empty. Its being defined in the while right above it?

Comment: Do a `print_r($row);` from within the while loop, to see what it says.  That will let you know what you're working with.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're only retrieving three columns from the query.

$account should be set to `$account = $row[1];`

$status should be set to `$status = $row[2];`

Comment: yeah, that the true answer. Just noticed it and you've posted it, great job ;)

Comment: Tim, your answer is partly correct. I did what another guy said, the connection wasn't set up properly for some reason. Thank you for your help i appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

You are only selecting 3 fields(id (0),account (1), status(2) )
so $account=$row[1] will echo account; There is no $row[3].
If you want to get all the columns use SELECT ***** FROM service WHERE.....

also to fetch values, use keys

```
    $query = "SELECT * FROM service WHERE status = 'Unpaid'";
    $result = mysql_query($query);  

       while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){

            $id = $row['id'];
            $dateEntered = $row['dateEntered'];
            $type = $row['type'];
            $account = $row['account'];
            $dateCompleted = $row['dateCompleted'];
            $notes = $row['notes'];
            $status = $row['status'];

        echo $account;
      // mailStatusUpdate($account, $status, $dateEntered);

    }
```